# Optimisation problem involving the $\| \cdot \|_2$ norm

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

> Let $x = (3,4,5)$ and let $A = \{z = (z_1,z_2,z_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : z_1+z_2+z_3 = 1\}$. Prove the existence and uniqueness of solution to the nonlinear optimization problem
>
> $$min_{z \in A} \|z-x\|_2^2$$

I would say we should try to take care of the side condition $z \in A$ first. We can do this by setting $z_3 = 1 - z_1 -z_2$ and obtain:

$$ \|z-x\|_2^2 = \langle z-x,z-x \rangle_2 = (z_1-x_1)^2 + (z_2-x_2)^2 + (z_3-x_3)^2$$
$$=(z_1-x_1)^2 + (z_2-x_2)^2 + (1 - z_1 -z_2 - x_3)^2$$

$$=(z_1-3)^2 + (z_2-4)^2 + (-4 - z_1 -z_2)^2$$

So I guess we should proceed by calculating the Hessian and the gradient of the above term, we call it $f$, and we obtain:

$$\nabla f(x) = (4z_1+4,4z_2+2)^t$$

$$\nabla^2 f(x) = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0\\ 0 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$$

It can thus be easily seen that $z^* = (-1, -0.5, 2.5)$ is the unique minimum of $f$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Do you know anything about convex optimisation?

Comment: I know that a stationary point of a convex function is a mimimum. Is my approach not correct?

Comment: Seems fine to me, except you've missed a square over the norm.

Comment: You are right, I corrected the mistake.

Comment: Your direct approach is correct, but the way I interpreted the given question is that it wants you to prove existence and uniqueness without actually finding the minimiser, hence me asking you about convex optimisation. Observe that one actually require the objective function to be strictly convex to guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: Geometrically, you are looking for the shortest distance from the point $x$ to the plane $A$.